# SSL Error with 12045

Tags: cygwin, chef-infra, test-kitchen

I have written a chef cookbook for windows platform. I'm able to converge the cookbook. It is working fine with downloading the packages from the internal artifactory using "http", but unable to access "https" due to SSL ERROR 12045?

Comment: Remember that Chef's HTTPS settings only apply to Chef itself, for any external tool it calls, you'll need to configure it too.

Answer (score 0):

The server has an invalid SSL certificate (probably self-signed)

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/182888/how-to-handle-invalid-certificate-authority-error-with-wininet